# Uniform convergence of integrals over a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\mu$ be a regular $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $X$. Suppose we have a sequence of continuous functions
$$f_n: X \times [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (x,t) \mapsto f(x,t), $$
which converges pointwise to a continuous function $f: X \times [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
 Suppose the following:

1. There exists a $g: X \times [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $t \in [0,T]$ the integral of $g(\cdot, t)$ exists and for all $n$: $f_n \leq g$,
2. For each $t \in [0,T]$ we have that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f_n(\cdot,t) d\mu = \int_X f(\cdot,t), $$
3. For each $x \in X$ the convergence $f_n(x,\cdot) \rightarrow f(x,\cdot)$ is uniform.

Is this enough to conclude that the convergence 
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f_n(\cdot,t) d\mu = \int_X f(\cdot,t) $$
is uniform in $t$? Maybe a useful theorem to prove it would be Egonov's Theorem. 
 
I found the article

> Emanual Parzen, Some conditions for uniform convergence of integrals

where in the beginning of the article the author claims it is true and refers to a book. I looked into the book, but the notations and assumptions are too vague to me and the Theorem isn't stated in its proper form. I ask this question since I'm not sure if I interpreted the previous references correctly.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Equicontinuity_and_uniform_convergence) might help: Letting $F_n(t):= \int_X f_n(x, t)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ and $F(t):= \lim_{n\to \infty} F_n(t)$, we note that $F_n\to F$ uniformly on $[0, T]$ iff $F_n\to F$ pointwise and the $F_n$ are equicontinuous. As we are given pointwise convergence, we only need prove the equicontinuity of the $F_n$ or provide a counterexample where the $F_n$ are not equicontinuous.